# How do I create a view with three tables in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, inner-join, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a simple view using three tables in Oracle Apex. My three tables include SHOES, RELEASES, and RETAILERS:

```
SHOES
-----
SHOE_ID
NAME
(etc)

RELEASES
--------
SHOE_ID
RETAILER_ID
RELEASE_DATE
(etc)

RETAILERS
---------
RETAILER_ID
NAME
(etc)
```

I want to return the release dates, shoe names and retailer names for shoes that have been released. I tried to use inner join, but it keeps returning an error -- not sure what I'm missing.

```
CREATE VIEW RELEASES_BY_RETAILERS [RELEASE_DATE, SHOE, RETAILER] AS
SELECT RELEASES.RELEASE_DATE, SHOES.NAME, RETAILERS.NAME
FROM RELEASES
INNER JOIN SHOES ON SHOES.SHOE_ID = RELEASES.SHOE_ID
INNER JOIN RETAILERS ON RETAILERS.RETAILER_ID = RELEASES.RETAILER_ID;
```

My desired result is:

```
RELEASE_DATE      SHOE       RETAILER
-------------------------------------
2020-MAR-19       SHOE1      RETAILER1
2020-MAR-18       SHOE2      RETAILER3
(etc)
```

Comment: FYI, it's always useful to include the error message not just the fact that it is returning an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong parenthesis. You need to use `()` parenthesis.

Code should be like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW RELEASES_BY_RETAILERS (RELEASE_DATE, SHOE, RETAILER)  -- code change here
AS
SELECT RELEASES.RELEASE_DATE, SHOES.NAME, RETAILERS.NAME
FROM RELEASES
INNER JOIN SHOES ON SHOES.SHOE_ID = RELEASES.SHOE_ID
INNER JOIN RETAILERS ON RETAILERS.RETAILER_ID = RELEASES.RETAILER_ID;
```

Comment: That's it?! I've been going nuts! Thanks for the help.

Comment: The best manual Oracle has is the SQL Reference manual. If you get stuck for syntax, they've got little diagrams to help. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6